# android + firestore update: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make each user to be able to change only name and photo. And also i want to prevent any other data inputs. These are `rules` that i use.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{user} {
            allow read: if request.auth.uid == user;
            allow update: if request.auth.uid == user &&
                   request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['name', 'photo']) &&
                   request.resource.data.size() == 2 &&
                   request.resource.data.name is string &&
                   request.resource.data.photo is string;
        }
    }
}
```

This rule works fine when i am using `set()` method but it throws `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` exception when i use `update()`. I can't use `set()` method because it removes other fields. These are my java codes.

```
private void update(FirebaseAuth fbAuth, String sNewName, String sNewPhoto){
    if (fbAuth.getUid() != null) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", sNewName);
        map.put("photo", sNewPhoto);

        Log.d(TAG, "changeProfile.map:" + map);

        firebasefirestore.collection("users")
                .document(fbAuth.getUid())
                .update(map)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "changeProfile.onSuccess");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@android.support.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "changeProfile.onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the actual values in the map?  What happens if you remove the update rule?

Comment: i get `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` exception. but update rule needs to stay

Comment: What about my other question?

Comment: i put strings in the map

Comment: Yes, what are the actual values?

Comment: `01-14 01:53:05.254 9332-9332/*: changeProfile.map:{photo=photo3, name=tmp3}
01-14 01:53:07.024 9332-9332/*: changeProfile.onFailure: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`